# Heronian tetrahedra with pairwise non-congruent, equal area faces

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry

**Reference:** https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronianTetrahedron.html lists some Heronian tetrahedra that are disphenoids.

- Are there any Heronian tetrahedra with all faces having same area but are mutually non-congruent triangles?

If the answer is "no", will (say) allowing the volume of the tetrahedron alone to be irrational have an impact on the answer?

It is easy to see that there are no tetrahedra (not only Heronian ones) with all faces mutually non-congruent and having same perimeter (rather than area).

Note (March 5, 2024): as follows from the comment from terceira, the question has an emphatic negative answer. Maybe whether a hexahedral box formed by 6 quads can have all faces mutually non congruent and with further constraints - say equal area and perimeter or with integer length edges - could be of some interest.

Comment: A tetrahedron with equal area faces is a disphenoid.  This is sometimes (mistakenly) known as Bang's theorem and has nothing to do with the tetrahedron  being heronian.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I understand since any tet with all faces equal in area necessarily is a disphenoid, the question has a straight negative answer.